# Ignore json POJO fields not mapped in object in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have pojo which has many fields. I have set value some field. But when i create json, whole pojo create a json . here is the code i have used:

1. Pojo

   ```
   public class BasicInfoModel  {
     private String client_id="";
     private String father_name="";
     private String mother_name="";        
     private String gendar="";
    //Getter and setter
    }
   ```
2. Repository code

   ```
    public BasicInfoModel getBasicInfo() {
       BasicInfoModel lm = new BasicInfoModel();
       lm.setFather_name("Enamul Haque");
       return lm;
      }
   ```
3. Controller code

   ```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/get_donar_basic_info", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces ="application/json")   
     public @ResponseBody BasicInfoModel getBasicinfo(){
      return repository.getBasicInfo();
     }
   ```
4. But my json is resposne like bellow:

   ```
   {
   "client_id": "",
   "father_name": "Enamul Haque",
   "mother_name": "",
   "gendar": ""
   }
   ```

   I have set value to father_name but i have seen that i have found all the value of pojo fields. I want get only set value of father_name and ignor other value which is not set in repository.
5. My json look like bellow: I will display only father_name.how to display bellow like json from above code?

   ```
    { 
    "father_name": "Enamul Haque"

    }
   ```

   Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

Json include non null values to ignore null fields when serializing a java class

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

## Jackson allows controlling this behavior at either the class level:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class BasicInfoModel { ... }
```

## at the field level:

```
public class BasicInfoModel  {
   private String client_id="";

   @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
   private String father_name="";

   private String mother_name="";   

   private String gendar="";

   //Getter and setter
}
```

from jackson 2.0 use [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html) use

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

You can also ignore the empty values

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

Comment: @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)  is working fine. If i set empty value like lm.setMother_name(""); what happen then.

Comment: you can also ignore empty values `JsonInclude.Include NON_EMPTY` @EnamulHaque

Comment: thanks Is it possible in this repository.getBasicInfo() method display json which is added in this method and other field will ignor

Comment: what's wrong adding this on POJO class? @EnamulHaque

Comment: some time i need json like {"father_name": "Enamul Haque",
"mother_name": ""}  if i use class level it ignor all the empty value. i want to avoid all other field is not added in  getBasicInfo() method.

Comment: i think you are looking some thing like this https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria @EnamulHaque

Answer (score 0):

Add the @JsonIgnoreProperties("fieldname") annotation to your POJO.

Or you can use @JsonIgnore before the name of the field you want to ignore while deserializing JSON. Example:

```
 @JsonIgnore
 @JsonProperty(value = "client_id")
 @RequestMapping(value = "/get_donar_basic_info", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces ="application/json")   
 public @ResponseBody BasicInfoModel getBasicinfo(){
  return repository.getBasicInfo();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore field at class level by using **@JsonIgnoreProperties** annotation and specifying the fields by name:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "client_id" })
public class BasicInfoModel  {
      private String client_id="";
      private String father_name="";
      private String mother_name="";        
      private String gendar="";
     //Getter and setter
     }
```

Or you can use @JsonIgnore annotation directly on the field.

```
public class BasicInfoModel  {
  @JsonIgnore
  private String client_id="";
  private String father_name="";
  private String mother_name="";        
  private String gendar="";
 //Getter and setter
 }
```

You can read [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization) more about this.

Comment: ambiguous answer. Can you elaborate and provide your references ?
TIA :)

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope this will clear your doubts :)